# Celery chord callback not executing

Tags: python, celery

I've been trying to solve this problem for a few days but still haven't found any solution. I have the following code:

```
@app.task(name='taggers')
def taggers(text: str) -> dict:
   return {'tags': get_tags(text), 'text': text}


@app.task(name='entitied')
def entitied(text: str) -> dict:
   return {'entities': get_entities(text)}


@app.task(name='persist_task_es')
def persist_task_es(data: list, document: dict) -> None:
   logger.error('persist task')
   TaskElastic.create_or_updated_task_document(document, data)


@app.task(name='init_planner', ignore_result=True, rate_limit='1/s')
def init_planner() -> None:
   try:
       user_tasks = get_user_tasks()
       for user_task in user_tasks:
           text = f"{user_task['title']} {user_task['plan']['title']}"
           chained_tasks = chain(chord([taggers.s(text), entitied.s(text)], persist_task_es.s(user_task)))
           chained_tasks.delay()

   except Exception as e:
       logger.error(e)
       logger.info('Indexation error', extra={
           "error": e
       })
```

It executes normally, without any error. The problem is that the task persist_task_es never executes. I have tried several alternatives (like this one [Celery not running chord callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546120/celery-not-running-chord-callback)) but still, not executing. Could you please help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came with a solution for this. The task was actually executing, but I couldn't see the output as it was using a delay (`chained_tasks.delay()`). I changed that to `chained_tasks.apply()` and then I could see the output and see that the task was having some bugs I couldn't see before.